# Compare Strings in List View in android

Tags: android, listview

I am developing an Android app in which there are two list views. When user clicks on items of first list view that must be added to second list view. This is I have implemented correctly. But my problem is strings must not be repeated in second list view. Means if String A is there in list view 1 and I click on it, it moves to list view 2 and if again I click on String A, it should prompt message(Message will be handled by me). Here is my code. What am I missing?

```
ArrayList<String> arr2;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2;
arr2 = new ArrayList<String>();

lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) {
        String selected = lv1.getItemAtPosition(arg2).toString();
        arr2.add(selected);
        adapter2 =  new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arr2);
        lv2.setAdapter(adapter2);
        adapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```

Comment: Have You tried to use Set instead of simple array in adapter (Sets are not allowing repeats)?

Comment: No.I have't use it yet

Comment: add() for Set returns false if item wasn't added. And it might be faster than ArrayList.contains().

Answer (score 3):

probably this will work.

```
String selected = lv1.getItemAtPosition(arg2).toString();



if (!arr2.contains(selected)) {

    //add item in second ListView

    arr2.add(selected);

} else {
    show popup
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Finally, got it....

```
   if (!arr2.contains(selected)) {
       arr2.add(selected);
       adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter < String > (getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arr2);
       lv2.setAdapter(adapter2);
       adapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();

   } else {
       Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Already Contains", 1000).show();
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you save an ArrayList (your arr2) and check if arr2 already contains the string selected.

```
if(arr2.contains(selected)){
    //continue with something else
}else{
    //add to list and refresh Fragment
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Contains method and check whether particular value exists in arr2 if it returns false then only perform arr.add(selected)

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
arr2.add(selected);
```

To

```
if(!arr2.contains(selected)){
    arr2.add(selected);
}
```